# Steady-State Thermal Conduction Calculations

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics, energy, units, thermal-conductivity

I'm working on a question for class where we need to solve for the heat flux in a system. The problem is stated ad follows:

> A $2 \; \mathrm{mm}$ thick glass sheet is being used for a window. The thermal conductivity of glass is $1.7 \; \mathrm{J/(m \cdot K \cdot s)}$. The temperature outside is $-20 \; \mathrm{^\circ C}$ and that inside is $20 \; \mathrm{^\circ C}$. Assuming steady-state is reached, how far into the glass sheet, from the high-temperature side, will the temperature be $+15 \; \mathrm{^\circ C}$.

I understand how to do the problem, I'm just having difficulty with unit correlation.

My first step was to calculate the heat flux. Since the system already reached steady-state I used the following equation: $q=-k \; \mathrm{d}T/\mathrm{d}x$. Then I used the value of $q$ to solve for how far into the glass the temperature will be $15 \; \mathrm{^\circ C}$ : $\Delta x=-k \Delta T/q$

My teacher posted the solutions and my steps were correct just not the values. $k$ is given to us $k=1.7 \; \mathrm{J/m\cdot k\cdot s}$, the temperature in degrees celsius and length in mm. I converted $2\; \mathrm{mm}$ to $0.002 \; \mathrm{m}$. But the solution posted did not correlate the units for temperature. I'm just confused why that is, shouldn't the $20 \; \mathrm{^\circ C}$ be converted to kelvin or vice versa? This way they will cancel out properly in the calculation.
[image]

Any help is greatly appreciated and I've attached a photo of the solution provided to us to make my question more clear. Thanks

Comment: 1K = 1°C. It's a relatively straightforward conversion.

Answer (score 2):

The temperature difference is the same whether expressed in Kelvin degrees or Centigrade degrees. Your calculation is correct. Since you have not posted the solution which your teacher gave, I don't understand what difficulty you think you have found.

The solution is much simpler than you are making it.

The flux $q$ through the glass is constant (there is nowhere else for it to go to or come from) and the thermal conductivity $k$ is also constant (it does not change with temperature or position in the glass sheet). You can deduce from the equation $q=-k dT / dx$ that the temperature gradient $dT / dx$ is also constant.

This means that the temperature varies linearly with distance from -20C on one side to +20C on the other side. It is a straightforward application of linear algebra to find where the temperature reaches a particular intermediate value. The only other information you need is the thickness of the glass pane (2mm). The values of the thermal conductivity $k$ of the glass and the flux $q$ are both irrelevant.

Answer (score 1):

The Celsius temperature $t$ is defined through the equation (see [here](http://www.bipm.org/en/publications/si-brochure/kelvin.html))

$$t = T – T_0,\qquad\qquad(1)$$

where $T$ is the thermodynamic temperature and $T_0 = 273.15\,\mathrm{K}$.

Note that, contrary to what many people believe, kelvin and degree Celsius are not two units for the same quantity, but two units for *two different quantities*, the thermodynamic temperature and the Celsius temperature.

However, from (1) we have $\Delta t = \Delta T$, and the two units are defined so that for any temperature difference,

$$\Delta T/\mathrm{K} = \Delta t/^\circ\mathrm{C}.$$

Since the definition of thermal conductivity involves a temperature difference, this can be expressed either in kelvin or in degree Celsius without changing the numerical value of the thermal conductivity or the equations, that is,

$$\frac{k}{\mathrm{W/(K\,m)}} = \frac{k}{\mathrm{W/(^\circ\mathrm{C}\,m)}}.$$